# How to make a search bar that filters the list with their class attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a search bar that filters the list with their name(eg:orange, copper). Is there any way to filter the results by using their class attribute.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("search-bar");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

  if (input.value === "") {
    [...li].forEach((liElement) => {
      liElement.style.display = "none";
    });
  } else {
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
      txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}

myFunction();
```

```html
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="search-bar" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search...">
<ul id="myUL" style="display:block">
  <li><a class="color fruit" href="#">Orange</a></li>
  <li><a class="chemical" href="#">H2SO4</a></li>
  <li><a class="animal car" href="#">Jaguar</a></li>
  <li><a class="element" href="#">Copper</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are going to enter input with spaces, so it would be better to make it into an array. Also, you have classes in `a` i.e using `a.classList` that will return classes in an array-like data structure.

Now you're having two arrays, so you can filter the result if all input classes array exists in any of the `a` classes.

*The best part is you can search even in reverse order like `car animal` and it would give you `Jaguar`.*

*It searches partially and also search for partial input also like `a c` or `c a` gives `Jaguar`.*

```js
function isClassExist(inputClasses, anchorClasses) {
  return inputClasses.every(ic => anchorClasses.some(ac => new RegExp(`\\b${ic}`).test(ac)))
}

function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("search-bar");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

  if (input.value === "") {
    [...li].forEach((liElement) => {
      liElement.style.display = "none";
    });
  } else {
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
      const regex = new RegExp(`\\b${input.value.toLowerCase()}`);

      const inputClassesAsArray = input.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
      const anchorClassesAsArray = [...a.classList];

      if (isClassExist(inputClassesAsArray, anchorClassesAsArray)) {
        li[i].style.display = "block";
      } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}

myFunction();
```

```html
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="search-bar" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for class...">
<ul id="myUL" style="display:block">
  <li><a class="color fruit" href="#">Orange</a></li>
  <li><a class="chemical" href="#">H2SO4</a></li>
  <li><a class="animal car" href="#">Jaguar</a></li>
  <li><a class="element" href="#">Copper</a></li>
</ul>
```